# Making games SLI compatible?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, sli

I've been thinking about getting a second GTX970 and having an SLI setup, I saw the list of games that support SLI just out of the box, but this seems like a very lacking list. From forums and articles I've read the general consensus seems to be that SLI can work for games that don't support it right away, but it requires "more work" than just getting one faster graphics card. I'm not worried by the though of having to tweak around to get the most out of both cards, but I can't really find any solid information on what "work" needs to be done. I've read about creating profiles in the Nvidia control panel, but from people saying it needs work, this seems like too simple a solution?
In short - what do I need to do to get games that do not natively support SLI to utilize both cards as best as possible? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: SLI is handled by the drivers not the programmer of the software.  Should clarify you can throw a $3,000 SLI setup at Cuphead but it won’t use but a fraction of it.

Comment: Right OK, so say for example a game like just cause 3, which officially does not support SLI, bit it could easily benefit from the extra power, would I be able to make that game use both cards despite it not coming with support pre-packaged?

Comment: Where did you determine [Just Cause 3](https://wccftech.com/sli-ight-confusion-with-sli-in-just-cause-3-its-definitely-possible-nvidia-employee-mispoke/) doesn’t support SLI?  Of course a single GTX970 is going to such overkill that your system will never attempt to use more resources then a single GTX970

Comment: Was looking at the wrong Just Cause game but it still won’t require more then a GTX970 you can throw more power but the engine only scales so much.  [You can also force it.](https://steamcommunity.com/app/225540/discussions/0/485622866452667490/)

Comment: So when the frame rate drops in a game because something big happened, could those not be ironed out by the second card? I'm not expecting an perfect, double speed result, but I'm confused as to why a game like just cause 3 (to use that example again) could make use of a 1080's added power to keep thing fps ~60, but a second 970 would be too much power to be of use?

Comment: The engine has to be optimized to use SLI but you can force it.  Outside of forcing it through the Nvidia software there isn’t another way

Comment: Right, OK that makes sense. So making those custom profiles is all the tweaking? And then the quality of those results is engine specific?

Comment: For the most part, SLI isnt worth the investment.  Numbers vary, but rarely will you get much of an increase in performance.  I believe 20% is about the average and its extremely rare to get close to 50%.  If you want more power, buy a better graphics card.